# Mobile PWA is standalone, but not after returning from device photos

Tags: android, google-chrome, progressive-web-apps, photo

PWA standalone single-page app, running Chrome 79 on Android.

Comes up standalone, no problem.  In one section I have a tag to get an image from the device library.

```
<input id="get-image" type="file" accept="image/*" >
```

I tap on "Choose File" to select a file (which works fine), and come back (with or without a picture).  Upon return the app is no longer standalone, but appears to be in a Chrome custom tab.  The only way I can return to standalone is to refresh, *which would be a bad thing in this context.*  I can switch to fullscreen, but not standalone (the device header bar goes away in fullscreen, *also bad*).

There was a similar issue related to third party logins, which was fixed, reappeared and supposedly to be fixed again *(I added a comment there)*.[Standalone PWA breaks login](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46411192/standalone-pwa-breaks-login)

Since the app is a single page app, chrome is returning to the start url, which is in the scope (from the manifest), so it should return to standalone.  So I'm a bit stumped.

This seems like a chrome issue, but I'd love it if there's a workaround.